# Dynamically changing the background of ListView child

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

I read many other posts, but most, if not all of them tell you to override one of the methods and put change the background then. I want to change it outside of the ListView Adapter class, so I tried doing this. It doesn't seem to work. I do however get the object, nut it wont change its background.

```
RelativeLayout item;
        item = (RelativeLayout) listView.getAdapter().getView(0, null, listView);
        item.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
```

Thank you.

Comment: Any reason changing outside of adapter? Even if you change outside adapter it will be reset once you scroll as views will be recycled by adapter  So i think best place to change background is adapter only.

Comment: @PrakashS I am making a list of times, and I want to highlight the nearest time. so if its 10:44 and the next time is 10:55 I want that to be highlighted. But that needs to be done with in the class that I am working on and it needs to be dynamic.

Comment: That you can do it in adapter only. Find the nearest time save it in a variable and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()  with in getView function check the variable and set color if it is nearest one. In this way color will be retained even when views recycled.

Comment: @PrakashS, thanks, but I am a little confused, where do I put `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` and where am I changing the color, I only know upcoming times once the adapter has been set, I would also want to update it on onresume, so it would highlight the next time if available.

Comment: In which ever function you are finding upcoming time you can  call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(). Once notifyDatasetchanged is called adapter relayout the the list items. getView() of adapter will be called for all the visible list items you can set color in getView() of adapter

Comment: @PrakashS. I am sorry I am being so difficult, I am new to android. As far I understood it would look like something like this:  `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        RelativeLayout item;
        item = (RelativeLayout) listView.getAdapter().getView(0, null, listView);
        item.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);` Is that correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160898/discussion-between-prakash-s-and-edon-freiner).

Comment: @PrakashS Hi, I realized an issue that I forgot to let you know about, I am using the `ListView` in 2 locations, for ruffly the same purpose, however they have 2 separate lists of times in them. I would want to highlight one and not the other. but using this approach seems that it would highlight both, is there a way to distinguish them from each other? Thank you.

Comment: Write a function in adpter which sets a flag to highlight or not. Call this function when ever u want to highlight

Comment: @PrakashS something like a static boolean method?

Comment: No need of static method. Let it be member fucnction. You would have created two instances of adapter for two listview. Set for the instance in which you want to highlight.

Comment: I did this: `public void highlightNextZman() {
        for (int i = 0; i < getCount(); i++) {
            if (i == ZmanimListTab.getUpComingZmanPosition() && i != -1) {
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(142, 96, 97));

            }    
        }
    }` But how do I get the convertView in there, since it cannot access it outside of the adapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the nearest time save it in a variable and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
  if(time is nerest time) {
    convertView. setBackgroundColor(Color. YELLOW)
  } else {
    convertView. setBackgroundColor("default color")
  }
}
```